# How can i make an html button automatically set?

Tags: php, html

I have three pages page1, page2 and page3. My page1 have a button and it is an input in form having method POST. So press this button goes to page2, so i can pass a value from page1 to page2. But in page2 it is automatically redirected to page3, then how can i pass this value passed from page1 into page3 through page? In my opinion if any way to automatically set a button can make it possible.

Comment: a) without your code, we can't take a look at your code. b) seems what you need is a tutorial in sessions.

Comment: the client side can send the data to the server using forms input. and the server can send the data to the client while it build the form e.g `echo "<input type="hidden" value="value">";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways off the top of my head. The first is to keep passing the variables across with the forms.  The second is to place the collected variable into a session when received by the second form and pick it up again on the third form.

First Option:

Page1.php:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
  <input type="text" name="input_one">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit to page 2">
</form>
```

Page2.php:

```
<?php if( isset( $_POST[ 'input_one' ] ) { $input1 = $_POST[ 'input_one' ]; } ?>
<form method="post" action="page3.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="input_one" value="<?php echo ( $input1 ? $input1 ? '' ); ?> >
  <input type="text" name="input_two"  >
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit to page 3">
</form>
```

Page3.php

```
<?php if( isset( $_POST[ 'input_two' ] ) { $input2 = $_POST[ 'input_two' ]; } ?>
```

Second Option:

Page2.php

```
<?php if( isset( $_POST[ 'input_one' ] ) { session_start(); $_SESSION[ 'input1' ] = $_POST[ 'input_one' ]; } ?>
```

Page3.php

```
<?php if( $_SESSION[ 'input1' ] != null ) echo $_SESSION[ 'input1' ]; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got another better idea from your answer.

Comment: @user618596 Great at least your up and running, would be grateful if you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use cookies?

**PAGE 1:**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="sometext" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**PAGE 2:**

```
$sometext=$_POST['sometext'];
setcookie('sometext', $sometext, time()+86400);
header('Location: /page3.php');
```

**PAGE 3:**

```
$sometext=$_COOKIE['sometext'];
```